# Why can I connect this struct in boost::signals2?

Tags: c++, boost, struct

The [boost signals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/signals2.html) library contains the following code in its [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/signals2/tutorial.html):

```
struct HelloWorld
{
  void operator()() const
  {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
  }
};
```

```
boost::signals2::signal<void ()> sig;

HelloWorld hello;
sig.connect(hello); (*)

sig();
```

However, I cannot grasp why this works. As far as I can see, `connect` should get a `void()` method, but instead it gets a `HelloWorld&` in (*). Why does this even work?

Comment: Have you read the [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/signals2/tutorial.html#id3351478)? Also, focus on _one_ question per post, and make sure that this specific question shines.

Comment: It's called a _functor_ class.

Comment: @Zeta I wager the OP _should_ focus on one of the two. It seems he [paired down a three-in-one question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27256436/boost-use-of-struct) into a two-in-one question. Still not quite correct, but yeah.

Comment: @sehe Thanks for your answer. I am waiting till I can accept it as answer. Now I have something to start reading about it.

Comment: I've tried to salvage the question. I've merged your questions into a single one, which doesn't invalidate sehe's or reymabel's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The struct is popularly known as a "functor".

In fact it's a regular object overloading the *function call operator* (`operator()`), so you can do:

```
struct X { void operator()(int x) { std::cout << x << "\n"; } };

int main() {
    X printer;
    printer(3);
}
```

which will print `3` to `std::cout`.

---

Boost Signals2 accepts any "callable object".

This includes

- functors
- function pointers
- any object with an implicit conversion to function pointers
- ...

Refer to e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Callable for more information

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `HelloWorld` has a "function call" operator, as described in [over.call]:

> `operator()` shall be a non-static member function with an arbitrary
>   number of parameters. It can have default arguments. It implements the
>   function call syntax
>
> *postfix-expression*
>   ( *expression-list*<sub>opt</sub> )
>
> where the postfix-expression evaluates to a class object and the
>   possibly empty *expression-list* matches the parameter list of an
>   `operator()` member function of the class. Thus, a call `x(arg1,...)`
>   is interpreted as `x.operator()(arg1, ...)` for a class object `x` of
>   type `T` if`T::operator()(T1, T2, T3)` exists and if the operator is
>   selected as the best match function by the overload resolution
>   mechanism (13.3.3).

You passed an *instance* of the struct, and `sig()` will invoke `operator()` on the instance.

See the [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/signals/tutorial.html#idp425136992) in the boost documentation.